# Is it possible to put existing/shared Content type fields as Feature code each in their own individual file to simplify/avoid git merge conflicts?

Tags: 7, entities, features

We have a set of content types that share common fields - in that we re-use them in several content types.

When recreating these content types as a Feature, the fields are all in one large file. This has proven to be difficult when resolving git merge conflicts when people adjust/remove/or add fields to content types as a normal part of development. The git ===== >>>>> <<<<< conflict markers 'cross over' different fields and make it hard to see how the merge should be done correctly.

I think a better solution is to have each field in its own file, even if there are hundreds, the host file system should be able to handle this, perhaps even use of directories may help, this would avoid complex merge conflict resolutions.

Is this single file per field possible?

Answer (score 2):

We faced similar problems, what we did was, we created a 4 features of similar fields that were used in multiple content types. This made sure that if a person is working on a similar funtionaltiy, he is responsible for all the content types.
Yes, we still need to be careful for this, but dividing it into multiple features did solve many issues.